# Roslyn code generated file need to save customized location

Tags: code-generation, filepath, roslyn

I need to change save file location to the other directory folder.
Right now it is saving current root folder only.
 Can you help me?.

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);             
            var root = await tree.GetRootAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) as CompilationUnitSyntax;
            var oldNamespace = root.Members.Single(m => m is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax) as NamespaceDeclarationSyntax;
            var classDeclarations = oldNamespace.Members.Where(m => m is ClassDeclarationSyntax);
            var newNamespace = SyntaxFactory.NamespaceDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseName(@namespace)).NormalizeWhitespace();
            newNamespace = newNamespace.AddMembers(classDeclarations.Cast<MemberDeclarationSyntax>().ToArray());
            root = root.ReplaceNode(oldNamespace, newNamespace).NormalizeWhitespace();
            string newCode = root.ToFullString();                    
            File.WriteAllText(Test.cs, root.ToFullString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work:

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\path\to\thing\Test.cs", root.ToFullString());
```